# Immediate window not executing selenium webdriver code

Tags: visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, immediate-window

Verified in both VS2019 and VS2022.

I just recently started noticing that I wasn't able to execute selenium webdriver code in the immediate window anymore.

Before, I know for a fact I was able to perform different **driver** actions in the immediate window but now I'm just getting the following message:
[image]

Did something change recently that's causing this with selenium? I've done the thing where I use the **Watch** window to perform the evaluation and I guess that works OK if I'm wanting to evaluate the specific line of code the debugger is on.

One of the great things I loved about the immediate window was being able to type in code that wasn't even in my program to do some testing if I needed to. That's immeasurably helpful with writing test automation so I don't have to stop and start my debug process every time I want to try out a new piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure I figured out the cause. Something with the **Selenium.WebDriver** nuget package with a 4.0+ version causes it. I'll have to do some more digging to figure out *why* tho.

I tested dropping the package version down to 3.141.0 and I was able to execute code in the immediate window again.